# How To Block Input in Java?

Tags: java

**How can I block input from keyboard and mouse when my Java application is running**.
Like we block input in AutoIt with **BlockInput(1)** , I also want to do same in Java.

Comment: On what environment? Swing? Would you please be more specific?

Comment: Am not sure i fully understand but on a general not a user wont be able to input anything into your program if you ont ask for it. Could you just clarify a bit?

Comment: A bit related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718525/block-all-other-input-to-an-application-and-control-it-from-a-wrapper-in-java

Comment: @mschonaker  I want this functionality for simple JAVA applications. Like my program is running and user cannot use mouse or keyboard to cancel the application(E.g user cannot close the GUI , once it is started)

Comment: @DaMainBoss Yes, But the user can close my GUI in the middle of the program if he wants to, I don't want that to happen by blocking Input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only answer for a swing application. For your main frame you should have this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

//or if you are using awt

 Frame frame = new Frame();
 frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     // handle the window closing event here
  });
```

Comment: oh ok cool..let me know if you have any problem.(just comment here)

Comment: But this blocks window closing operations only! @Rizwan606, is it what you asked? I think you wanted to block all user input (keyress, mouse clicks etc)

Comment: @AlexR ,Yes I wanted to block all user input,but this is close to what i wanted,because i wanted that my GUI should not be closed once it is running.Of course your answer is helpful too,but i will have to make extra GUI(JWindow) in your case.This answer is not close to perfect,but ok for now,if I get any new answer that meets all functionality(blocking all mouse and keyboard inputs,mouse cannot move,keyoard cannot enter any text),i will mark it as correct.

Comment: By the way in both the answers,Yours and DaMainBoss's answer,the GUI can still be closed from "Task Manager" :-(which was not what i wanted. your answer is helpful too. Thanks Anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [This](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) - **JNativeHook**, a global keyboard & mouse listener library for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Create insance of transparent window (Window, not Frame or JFrame) and put it exactly on your application's window. User will not see anything (because it is transparent). But mouse and keyboard events will arrive to this transparent window.

Tip: the window should not be 100% transparent. In this case this trick does not work. put opacity 0.01.